# ESP8266 direct write to memory by byte

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

How to directly, without using the EEPROM library, overwrite the flash memory of the PROGMEM variable byte by byte? Also, how can I determine the memory addresses in which I can save my data byte-by-byte energy-independently without harm to the main program, without using the EEPROM library?

In my opinion, a line consisting of '#' characters should come out at the end and the changes should remain after the power is turned off, but the chip goes into an endless boot loop.

```
char myString[] PROGMEM = "Line example in PROGMEM";
void setup() {
Serial.begin(74880);
Serial.println(myString);
uint32_t adr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(myString);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myString); i++) {
*((uint8_t *)adr + i) = 35;
  }
Serial.println(myString);
}
```

Comment: This is just not the way flash memory works. This is the kind of question where it looks like you may be being overly prescriptive - what problem are you *actually* trying to solve by doing this? Why do you not want to use the EEPROM library?

Comment: I am convinced that EEPROM cannot update one byte at a time, even with minor changes, the entire sector will be overwritten. I also want to understand how flash writing works.

Comment: What make you think you can write one byte to flash memory without erasing a sector? You need to have better understanding about [flash memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory). Any bits that have been set to 0 by programming can only be reset to 1 by erasing the entire block.

Comment: I read about [flash memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory). :"The erase operation can only be performed on a block basis; all cells in the erase segment must be erased together. However, programming of NOR cells can generally be done one byte or word at a time."  + "NAND flash can address it by pages, words, and bits." While there is a lot of incomprehensible to me, I continue to work with information in the context of esp8266 based on esp01